# Images of nivo slider distorted

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I have a nivo slider on the bottom of the page (footer) [Page-Link](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/shabani-stuckateur/shabani-stuckateur.html)
The images of this slider are distorted.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
            <img src="img-slider1.png" alt=""  />
            <img src="img-slider2.png" alt=""  />
            <img src="img-slider3.png" alt=""  />
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer .slider { width: 500px; height: 148px; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px; }
```

Anyone an idea what is wrong with this nivo slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your page's source code says that nivo-slider.css is not found at its supposed location:

```
http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/shabani-stuckateur/nivo-slider.css
```

Try to make it available and everything will be fine.

Checkout this demo with valid css source: http://jsbin.com/eguVoGA/1/

Comment: Hey thank you. I've changed but now it pushs my text on footer away and I put 500px width to that slider div.

Answer (score 0):

Well...First of all, instead of using **visibility: hidden;**, which only hides the object but it physically remains there. Try using **display: none;**. That should fix the problem with the infinite space created below the footer.